# SSAS 2005 attribute relationship

Tags: ssas

a screen shot is worth a thousand words, so here we are.

I have DimDate table as underlying table for a Dim Finacial Time dimension. It shows each day (DateKey), the financial week no the day is in (fYear_weekNo) and the financial year (fYear). Just ignore other columns since they are not used in Dim Financial Time dimension.

[image]

Here is the attribute relationship and user hierarchy (Finacial week) defined.

[image]

Here is the browser result of Finacial week of Dim Finacial Time dimension. There should be 52 weeks for each year. Instead, it shows each finacial year only has several week. It seems all finacial weeks are separated in all the financial years.

[image]

If I removed fYear_weekNo - FYear relationship

[image]

Then the result is correct (it shows 52 weeks for year 1). My question why is that?

[image]

I think there should be a relationship between fYear_weekNo - FYear relationship. Because even if it is correct, SSAS gives me a warning.

[image]

Comment: All right, I kind figure it out that the fYear Week No and f Year are not many - 1 relationship in my underlying table because the fYear Week No repeats for every financial year (1 - 52). So it's actually a many to many relationship.

Comment: Hi, you can review my suggestion in order to aim correct relations and a good performance.

Answer (score 0):

Using MSFT's SSAS you should make the right relationships between attributes in order to built an efficient attribute hierarchy.

Right now you are confusing the SSAS because many days are belong to some month and the same time the same days belongs to an another month. Same thing is happening for months to, some month belongs to a year and at the same time the same month belongs to an another year.

Consider that you are doing:

```
DAY_01 to MONTH_01
...
DAY_31 to MONTH_01

and then

DAY_01 to MONTH_02
...
DAY_31 to MONTH_02
```

To solve this consider the following example that a single day belongs only to one month and a single month belongs to only one year.

```
DAY_01_01_2000 to MONTH_01 to YEAR_2000
...
DAY_31_01_2000 to MONTH_01 to YEAR_2000

and then

DAY_01_02_2000 to MONTH_02 to YEAR_2000
...
DAY_31_02_2000 to MONTH_02 to YEAR_2000
```

First, make the relationships, for example the day must be ralated to month and the year, alse the month must be ralated to year.

The day attribute must look like:

```
->DAY
-->YEAR
-->MONTH
```

The month attribute must look like:

```
->MONTH
-->YEAR
```

The year attribute must look like:

```
->YEAR
->no relationship
```

Second, you must edit the key values for each attribute, you can do that using the properties window (note that if an attribute has more than one keys then you must also set the name of column with some name), in order to tell on SSAS that which day belongs to whitch month to witch year.

For day the key values must be:

```
year
month
day
```

For month the key values must be:

```
month
year
```

For year the key values must be:

```
year
```

Now deploy and procces the cube again and the yellow triangle must disapear and get the correct result at the browser of dimention!